# Cross site scripting manipulation globally

Tags: c#, asp.net, cross-site

In our application we have a class called `GlobalPage.cs` this page inherits from `Page` we have Page load overrides and other there. It was called to our attention we need to add some security to our pages that contain textboxes (some are asp textboxes and others are html inputs). What we want to do is to be able to check all those fields globally from one place and not do it individually on each page. How can we achieve thi, possibly using the `GlobalPage.cs` ?

I would appreciate any input or help on what can be done.

Comment: What kind of checks? How do you imagine this to work?

Comment: I imagine it like, say anyone inputs somethign in mypage.aspx, so it must hit GlobalPage.cs through the loading or submit process so i would like to check certain inputs from only this one place, check for html like tags etc.. and encode them.

Comment: You _could_ override `page_load` on the base page and check for form elements to be valid, but this is likely to slow things down quite a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already some built in protection from malicious input. Make sure you did not turn it off.

```
<pages validateRequest="true"...>
```

Incoming values by themselves are not a problem for XSS. It is rendering of non-escaped values that causes problems. So while sanitizing input is somewhat useful there is no replacement for correct encoding of output.

Consider reading existing information on XSS protection in ASP.Net like [How To: Protect From Injection Attacks in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647397.aspx) (2.0, note that there are changes in 4.0 - [ASP.NET Request Validation](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147)).

Comment: Hello, yeah i went through this already, we have everything enabled yet there are still some inputs that asp does.net does not check, I am able to do in an email input this "blah@test.com" onMouseOver=alert(222)// and then i mouse over a link generated by it it pops that

Comment: @user1416156, So you already done reviews and fixes in your code for "correct encoding of output" and still have the issue? Sounds strange. There is no way to validate inputs in such a way that all possible variants of HTML rendering code will not cause XSS errors when rendering HTML based on input values - you must *properly* escape all vales that are coming from user input, no exceptions or shortcuts to that.

Comment: Basically we have the asp validation and some textboxes validate the input but apparently there are some missing validation so i want to create something in the global page to check the inputs for any javascript or html tags or attacks